# Use cell-based calculation to create table

Tags: excel, function, libreoffice-calc

There's a feature in Excel which I can't find or figure out in LibreCalc.

Suppose that I have a calculation over a series of cells such that cell A1 is an input and cell A2 is the output, with a whole series of intermediate cell-based calculations being used to arrive at the value in A2. Thus, A1 --> A2 is conceptually a function, call it f().

I want to create a table by creating a column of input numbers, a1,...,an, then having Calc apply my function to them so that the values f(ai) appear to the right of the column of input numbers.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53764995/edit) top provide existing data, what the desired output is and what you've tried so far (in this case the Excel formulas -- if I understand what you've written correctly)

Comment: For a simple example, suppose that A1 --> A2 converts from Fahrenheit to Celsius, and that I want a table providing the conversion from 0F to 100F, in steps of 1 degree. Obviously, that's a trivial formula, and you could just paste the formula into the column of desired results. In my case, the function is much more complicated and requires maybe 20 intermediate cells between the input and output.

Comment: Another way to look at this is that I want to automate the process of typing the input into A1, and copying the output from A2. I'd like a table of about 100 of these inputs and ouputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is the Data->Multiple Operations menu choice. Once you know which menu item, it's a matter of following your nose.